# $z$-invariant function equal to a polynomial of $z$

Tags: functions

If I have the expression $f(x,y) = \sum z^ig_i(x,y)$, i.e. a $z$-invariant function equal to a polynomial of $z$ whose coefficients do not depend on $z$, and it needs to hold for all $z$, can this only be true for $f = g_i = 0$ for all $i$?

Comment: Close. For all $i > 0, g_i(x,y) = 0$. But there is nothing that requires $g_0(x,y)$ to be zero.

Comment: good point. In fact, isn't $f = g_0$?

Comment: Yes. That is what it means.